# How to get complete yaml node child object from a parent yaml node?

Tags: yaml-cpp

I am trying to get a complete node object while parsing a yaml file.
My yaml data looks like similar to below data

```
---
Parent:
  Child1: ABC
  Child2:
    Subchild1: 123
    Subchild2: 456
  Child3: XYZ
...
```

The way I am trying to get the data is

```
YAML::Node parentNode = YAML::LoadFile(abc.yaml); // My yaml file name is abc

    if(!parentNode.IsNull())
    {
        if(parentNode.IsMap())
        {
            YAML::iterator it = parentNode.begin();
            std::cout << "Parent is " << it->first.as<std::string>() << std:endl; // Parent
            if(it->second.IsScalar())
            {
            }
            else if(it->second.IsMap())
            {
                YAML::Node rootChild = it->second;
                YAML::iterator chilItr = rootChild.begin();
                std::cout << "Child count is " << chilItr->second.size() << std:endl; // 3
                while(chilItr != rootChild.end())
                {
                    YAML::Node child = *chilItr;
                    if(child.IsMap()) //This causes exceetion
                    {
                        YAML::iterator ChildIterator = Child.begin();
                        std::cout << " Child is " << ChildIterator->first.as<std::string>() << std::endl;
                    }
                    chilItr++;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Why is `child.IsMap()` throwing an exception?
So basically the requirement is how can I get hold of a child YAML node object from a parent object?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you pasted the exact YAML file, or the exact code, that you're using, since your comment of `3` would not be what is printed, using your example. Here's the basic idea, using your example YAML file:

```
YAML::Node parentNode = YAML::LoadFile("abc.yaml");
if (parentNode.IsMap()) {
  YAML::iterator it = parentNode.begin();
  YAML::Node key = it->first;
  YAML::Node child = it->second;
  std::cout << "Parent is " << key.as<std::string>() << "\n"; // Parent
  if(child.IsMap()) {
    std::cout << "Child count is " << child.size() << "\n"; // 3

    // Now that you've got a map, you can iterate through it:
    for (auto it = child.begin(); it != child.end(); ++it) {
      YAML::Node childKey = it->first;
      YAML::Node childValue = it->second;

      // Now you can check the childValue object
      if(childValue.IsMap()) {
        // Iterate through it, if you like:
        for (auto it = childValue.begin(); it != childValue.end(); ++it) {
          // ...
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I actually want a child node with both key and value in it so that I can pass that node to another function instead of sending value alone. I don't to create a new node with key and value from iterator, but pass the child with both key and values as reference.

Comment: I actually want a child node with both key and value in it so that I can pass the reference of the node to another function instead of sending value alone. I don't want to create a new node with key and value from iterator, but pass the reference of the node.

Comment: @user3389312, based on your graph structure, there is no such node (there's no "key/value" node, just a key node and a value node). Why can't you pass both to your function?

Comment: If you don't want to pass both, then you can restructure your YAML, e.g., turn it into a sequence, and move the key to a field called `type`, or something.

Comment: Dereferencing the Yaml iterator gives a yaml node right ? Does this mean YAML::Map is not a single node object ?

Comment: @user3389312, dereferencing a *sequence* iterator gives a node. Dereferencing a *map* iterator gives you a pair with `first` and `second` nodes. Since YAML nodes can be either maps or sequences, both options are overloaded in the same iterator, which is what is confusing you.

Comment: In other words, if you do the wrong thing, you don't get a compile-time error; you get a run-time error, which is what's happening for you.